# A change in one object changes the second one too

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm creating two objects and assign them with a data from `IsolatedStorage`.
But when I change one object the second one changes too. ( I think the problem may be the pointers are the same, but I can't solve it. )

```
private ArrayOfClsSimpleData lstUsers;
private ArrayOfClsSimpleData tmpLstUsers;
```

in class' globals

```
tmpLstUsers = IsolatedStorageHelper.GetObject<ArrayOfClsSimpleData>("users");
lstUsers = IsolatedStorageHelper.GetObject<ArrayOfClsSimpleData>("users");
```

The first status of the arrays:

```
Debug.Write(lstUsers.Count)
```

**Output:** 2

```
Debug.Write(tmpLstUsers.Count)
```

**Output:** 2

The counts are the same as expected. But, after I add an item to one list, the other list gets updated too and the counts are still same.

```
lstUsers.Add(new ArrayOfClsSimpleData());


Debug.Write(lstUsers.Count)
```

**Output:** 3

```
Debug.Write(tmpLstUsers.Count)
```

**Output:** 3

---

EDIT : `IsolatedStorageHelper` class is something to help to get objects, save object etc. that I do use for simplifying things, so just think it as getting objects from `IsolatedStorage`.

it is implemented like this:

```
 public static T GetObject<T>(string key)
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(key))
        {
            return (T)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key];  // return the object 
        }

        return default(T); // if key doesn't exists , return default object
    }
```

So it just gets it from IsolatedStorage.
If you don't know isolated storage you can see it from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.105).aspx)

So, how can I fix the code so that I can change one without changing the other?

Comment: How and where do you set it?

Comment: But how is `IsolatedStorageHelper.GetObject<ArrayOfClsSimpleData>("myKey")` set?

Comment: How is your `IsolatedStorageHelper` implemented? It seems like it uses some sort of internal cache and returns the same object for the same key.

Comment: Is `myKey` actually different in both situations or is the key the same?

Comment: Then it returns the same object. No wonder it is the same when you edit it. Use two keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically `lstUsers` and `tmpLstUsers` are references to the same object. All you have to do is to create a new one and copy content from the original. If you need a quick solution, then you can do it like this (code below). I just guess that `ArrayOfClsSimpleData` is some kind of array.

```
lstUsers = IsolatedStorageHelper.GetObject<ArrayOfClsSimpleData>("myKey");
tmpLstUsers = new ArrayOfClsSimpleData();

foreach (object user in lstUsers) // I don't know the type of objects in ArrayOfClsSimpleData, so I wrote 'object', but you should use the actual type
    tmpLstUsers.Add(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the `Clone()` method of `IClonable` while fetching the object? looks like both list objects are getting same reference objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that IsolatedStorage is just returning two pointers to the same data. So unless you copy the data, all changes will ultimately be to the same underlying data.

Think of it as two copies of your home address. Anything you change on your home affects all copies of your address since it is just an address and not the home itself.

What you will want to do is clone your object. Built in collections have clone or copy methods built in to do shallow copies, or if you built something yourself you will need to implement it yourself

The easiest way is to implement the IClonable interface and to use the clone method to achieve your copying.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ICloneable.aspx

This basically involves going through and calling member wise clone for each complex object (which will copy all value types for you)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Comment: well can't change the implementation of the objects, but this could work too I guess

Comment: If the objects are not your own, or you otherwise can't change them, add the clone functionality via an extension method. That way it is always available anywhere you use the type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think cloning is necessary. Just create a new list instead of operating on the same instance. You can do that by calling `ToList()` on the returned instance:

```
lstUsers = IsolatedStorageHelper.GetObject<ArrayOfClsSimpleData>("myKey").ToList();
```

Comment: I will try this when I got the chance. And notify you about the result

Comment: Whoops. I misread your question. Any particular reason why you are using your own array implementation? Does it implement IEnumerable<T>? Otherwise ToList() won't work on it and I would withdraw this answer.